# Find all the idempotent elements of a structure

Tags: linear-algebra

So they've given me this problem, I'm not quite sure how to go about:

**Problem**

An element in some structure $(G,*)$ is idempotent if $a * a = a$. Determine all the idempotent elements of the operation $(\mathbb{R},*)$ where

$$x*y = xy + yy\ \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R} $$

I thought I could use the fact it was $(\mathbb{R},*)$ to conclude that it was an abelian groupm and therefore use its commutative property to use cancellation law and conclude that x and y are the same. However, this only applies with the addition operation with $(\mathbb{R},*)$ and that is not the operation I have here. Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By plugging in we find $$ a*a=a^2+a^2=2a^2$$
hence $a$ is idempotent if and only if $a=2a^2$. The solutions of this are $a=0$ and $a=\frac12$.

Comment: I see, thank you for the quick response.